# How to reference multiple columns in WHERE (x,y) IN (...)?

Tags: jooq

How can one implement the following [query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34270/4719) using JOOQ?

> SELECT whatever
> FROM t
> WHERE (col1, col2)
> IN ((val1a, val2a), (val1b, val2b), ...);

Specifically, how can one pass multiple columns on the left hand side of `IN`?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

> (col1, col2) IN (val1a, val2a), (val1b, val2b))

can be expressed as

> row(col1, col2).in(row(val1a, val2a), row(val1b, val2b))

Source: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/in-predicate-degree-n/